# using Strings in C/C++ -- [ ] after LPCTSTR

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

came across this and was wondering what it does

```
LPCTSTR szmyLPCTSTR; 

// doing _tcsncpy things with that string

//at the end then there is this line which i am not sure what it does
szmyLPCTSTR[122] = 0;
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LPCTSTR is simply a pointer to characters. It's adding a null terminator to the string.

Comment: Well, it *was* right, now it says it's an array, which is wrong.  An `LPCTSTR` is a pointer.

Comment: But why does it need to add a null terminator cant i just check for '/0'

Comment: I presume you mean `'\0'`, but `0` and `\0` are literally the same thing.  Well, in C anyway.  In C++ they have different types, but the assignment in your example will make both end up the same in this case.

Comment: @OliverCiappara: You don't show enough code to indicate why the null terminator has to be added. It may be truncating to a fixed length or something.

Comment: well thanks guys, i was under the impression that the null terminator was added automatically when you filled in the string, yes the string is getting truncated but does that mean that i have to add the null terminator every time i truncate the string

Comment: Adding the terminator **is** truncating the string.